# Regex to match pattern.one skip newlines and characters until pattern.two

Tags: python, regex

I need help with a regex for multi line skip until pattern  and couldn't see it already covered.

```
Name of person 
 Jack
 Nichol 
 Age 42
 .....
 .....
 ....
Name of person
 Andrew
 Jason
 Age 54
...
```

...
...

How do i match - something like `(Name.*(?:(\n)+).*(?:Age))`

consider the below -

```
interface TenGigE0/0/0/7



shutdown

!

interface TenGigE0/0/0/8



 bundle id 221 mode active

 lacp period short

 lacp period short receive 100

 lacp period short transmit 100

 carrier-delay up 100 down 100

 load-interval 30

 frequency synchronization

 !

 transceiver permit pid all

!

interface TenGigE0/0/0/9



 mtu 9216

 frequency synchronization

 !

 transceiver permit pid all

!

interface TenGigE0/0/0/10



 bundle id 237 mode active

 lacp period short

 lacp period short receive 100

 lacp period short transmit 100

 carrier-delay up 120000 down 150

 load-interval 30

 frequency synchronization
```

how do i match all the tengigex/x/x/x and corresponding  carrier-delay lines.

like below -

[   interface TenGigE0/0/0/8,     carrier-delay up 100 down 100]
[    interface TenGigE0/0/0/10,   carrier-delay up 120000 down 150]
...and so on.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you need to match? and what is the regex flavor? See https://regex101.com/r/hS2uJ3/1 or https://regex101.com/r/hS2uJ3/2

Comment: Name of Person + Age - all occurrences

Comment: The data is dummy is but the point is i want to match x then escape all newlines and characters untill y. repeat.

Comment: Ok, please update the question with the expected output and explain what *escape newlines and characters* mean.

Comment: updated the sample input and the output desired.

Answer (score 2):

To match the contents between the *closest* lines containing `tengige` and `carrier-delay` you need a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) (or an unrolled version):

```
(?sim)^([^\n]*TenGigE[^\n]*)(?:(?!TenGigE|carrier-delay).)*([^\n]*carrier-dela‌​y[^\n]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yG6pI8/4)

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZvSyJy):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^([^\n]*TenGigE[^\n]*)(?:(?!TenGigE|carrier-delay).)*([^\n]*carrier-delay[^\n]*)', re.DOTALL | re.M | re.I)
test_str = "interface TenGigE0/0/0/8\n bundle id 221 mode active\n lacp period short\n lacp period short receive 100\n lacp period short transmit 100\n carrier-delay up 100 down 100\n\ninterface TenGigE0/0/0/7\n\n\n\nshutdown\n\n!\n\ninterface TenGigE0/0/0/8\n\n\n\n bundle id 221 mode active\n\n lacp period short\n\n lacp period short receive 100\n\n lacp period short transmit 100\n\n carrier-delay up 100 down 100\n\n load-interval 30\n\n frequency synchronization\n\n !\n\n transceiver permit pid all\n\n!\n\ninterface TenGigE0/0/0/9\n\n\n\n mtu 9216\n\n frequency synchronization\n\n !\n\n transceiver permit pid all\n\n!\n\ninterface TenGigE0/0/0/10\n\n\n\n bundle id 237 mode active\n\n lacp period short\n\n lacp period short receive 100\n\n lacp period short transmit 100\n\n carrier-delay up 120000 down 150\n\n load-interval 30\n\n frequency synchronization"
print(p.findall(test_str))
# => [('interface TenGigE0/0/0/8', 'carrier-delay up 100 down 100'), ('interface TenGigE0/0/0/8', 'carrier-delay up 100 down 100'), ('interface TenGigE0/0/0/10', 'carrier-delay up 120000 down 150')]
```

**UPDATE**

A very powerful regex for extracting the same texts based on the unroll the loop technique (unrolled tempered greedy token):

```
(?sim)^([^\n]*TenGigE[^\n]*\n)[^T\n]*(?:T(?!enGigE)[^T\n]*|\n(?! carrier-delay)[^T\n]*)*(\n carrier-delay[^\n]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yG6pI8/5)

Comment: Please check this and let know if that is all you need or if you need to capture anything else inside the block.

Comment: Thanks It's close. But need _only_ - [interface TenGigE0/0/0/8,

 carrier-delay up 100 down 100] say in a list  and not the lacp or description or any  other stuff in between them. Accepting the answer. But refinement will be appreciated.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the regex and code. Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Comment: Thanks. Accepted the other answer and upvoted this one.

Comment: Your demo needs more than 200.000 steps to succeed!

Comment: Then it can be reduced 10 times with [`(?sim)^([^\n]*TenGigE[^\n]*)(?:(?!TenGigE|carrier-delay).)*([^\n]*carrier-delay[^\n]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/yG6pI8/4).

Answer (score 0):

You could come up with:

```
(?:^(interface\ TenGigE
(?:\d+/?){4}))
(?:(?!(?:carrier-delay|interface))[\s\S])+
(?P<carrier>carrier-delay\ .+)
```

In `Python` this would be:

```
import re
rx = re.compile("""
(?:^(interface\ TenGigE
(?:\d+/?){4}))
(?:(?!(?:carrier-delay|interface))[\s\S])+
(?P<carrier>carrier-delay\ .+)""", re.VERBOSE|re.MULTILINE)
matches = rx.findall(string)
```

Compared to @Wiktor's answer (which needs > 200k steps), this one only needs ~3k, see <kbd>[a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vY8tD5/3)</kbd> (thanks to him for spotting an inaccuracy before).

Comment: `\G` is not the point here. You yourself are using a tempered greedy token - that is the point. No need using the regex module here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Right you are, updated the answer. I have started with `\G` (had another solution on my mind). Still, why do you need more then 200.000 steps to succeed?

Comment: I have 20K only because OP did not confirm that the lines should start with *interface* and *carrier-delay*. The task was to find lines *containing* them. I can further enhance the performance by adding an anchor or/and unrolling the pattern, sure.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Damn it, you got me :)

Comment: :-) regexes really get everyone bugged. 2 confessions. the input data i provided was trimmed a bit - had to edit out the private stuff about interface descriptions. if matching only tengig followed by carrier-delay the scope is huge. eg. it finds a <teng ...shutdown...tengig...carrier-delay> thus giving inaccurate results. i have constrained it further. <tengig..description..carrier-delay>  paste the regex for the record. (tengigE.*(?:\r|\n)\s.des.*?)\n\n(?:.|\n)+?(Car.*?)\n  gmi

Comment: theres also another thing wish to add - despite it working perfectly fine in regex101 the regex didnt work on windows when i read the file into a buffer and ran the re.findall on it. so if working on windows - read the file into a buffer and print it to screen. paste that output to regex101 and build your regex.