# [FORKING]Python Regex - Re.Sub and Re.Findall Interesting Challenges

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Not sure if this is something that should be a bounty. II just want to understand regex better.

I checked the responses in the [Regex to match pattern.one skip newlines and characters until pattern.two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023556/regex-to-match-pattern-one-skip-newlines-and-characters-until-pattern-two) and [Regex to match if given text is not found and match as little as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860847/regex-to-match-if-given-text-is-not-found-and-match-as-little-as-possible/40860925#40860925) threads and read about `Tempered Greedy Token Solutions` and `Explicit Greedy Alternation Solutions` on RexEgg, but admittedly the explanations baffled me.

I spent the last day fiddling mainly with re.sub (and with findall) because re.sub's behaviour is odd to me.

.

**Problem 1:**

Given Strings below with characters followed by `/` how would I produce a SINGLE regex (using only either re.sub or re.findall) that uses alternating capture groups which must use `[\S]+/` to get the desired output

```
>>> string_1 = 'variety.com/2017/biz/news/tax-march-donald-trump-protest-1202031487/'
>>> string_2 = 'variety.com/2017/biz/the/life/of/madam/green/news/tax-march-donald-trump-protest-1202031487/'
>>> string_3 = 'variety.com/2017/biz/the/life/of/news/tax-march-donald-trump-protest-1202031487/the/days/of/our/lives'
```

**Desired Output Given the Conditions(!!)**

```
tax-march-donald-trump-protest-
```

**CONDITIONS: Must use alternating capture groups which must capture `([\S]+)` or `([\S]+?)/` to capture the other groups but ignore them if they don't contain `-`**

**I'M WELL AWARE that it would be better to use `re.findall('([\-]*(?:[^/]+?\-)+)[\d]+', string)` or something similar but I want to know if I can use `[\S]+` or `([\S]+)` or `([\S]+?)/` and tell regex that if those are captured, ignore the result if it contains `/` or doesn't contain `-` While also having used an alternating capture group**

**I KNOW I don't need to use `[\S]+` or `([\S]+)` but I want to see if there is an extra directive I can use to make the regex reject some characters those two would normally capture.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190726/discussion-on-question-by-failsafe-forkingpython-regex-re-sub-and-re-findall).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posted per request:

```
(?:(?!/)[\S])*-(?:(?!/)[\S])*
```

https://regex101.com/r/azrwjO/1

Explained

```
 (?:                           # Optional group
      (?! / )                       # Not a forward slash ahead
      [\S]                          # Not whitespace class
 )*                            # End group, do 0 to many times
 -                             # A dash must exist
 (?:                           # Optional group,  same as above
      (?! / )
      [\S] 
 )*
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @sln. Awesome!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
/([-a-z]+)-\d+
```

and take the first capturing group, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/smJzjG/1/).

Comment: Thanks. I know I can use that, but I really want to force the use of "([\S]+?)/" and force it to exclude anything captured that doesn't contain "-" using a single regex statement. I know I don't even need to use "[\S]+?", but I want it there to see if I can use an extra directive in regex to force it to drop some captures that [\S]+ would normally find. But yes, I want to force it to use "([\S]+?)/"